# Mongoose - populate method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `comments` collection with custom values for `_id` instead of mongo objectIds:

```
var exports = module.exports = CommentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({});
CommentsSchema.add({
_id : {type : Number, required : true, index: true, unique : true },
label:      {type: String, index: true, unique : true }//Should be unique
});
```

Records:

```
db.comments.insert{_id:1, label : 'some text'});
db.comments.insert({_id:2, label : 'some text'});
```

Another schema `Posts` which refers `Comments` as below

```
PostsSchema.add({
    comments : [{type : Number, ref: 'Comments' }],
});
```

I tried to use `mongoose.populate` method to get Comments data along with Posts data. But as I have custom ID for comments, I am not getting the comments data in posts.

```
Posts.find().populate('Comments').exec(function(err, posts){
console.log(posts);
});
```

I checked [mongoose populate docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate), which defines multiple options that can be passed for populate, but could not get that working as well. Is it possible to use `populate` method for custom defined "_id" or custom fields?

**Final Solution**
Using `CommentsSchema` and `PostsSchema` as as above, i got this working with below code.

```
Posts.find({}).populate('comments').exec(function(err, posts){
    console.log(posts);
    });
```

Comment: From you code it looks like you don't have a custom id for `Comments`

Comment: Updated the question with 'comments' schema with _id field.I tried adding it to schema, and still it didnt work.

Comment: If you have a numeric I'd, why do you make a ref type as String

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update posts schema here. I tried with both Number and String, but i could not get that working.

Comment: It seems that you should use populate('comments') - lowercased and ref type number. Populate takes name of the field as parametrr

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.. Finally got it working. Updated the post with answer.